# msnodesqlv8 - exec stored proc

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

In my NightWatch automation tests i need data in correct state before test is run. To set it up i need execute some stored procedures against MSSQL-2016 server. I use msnodesqlv8 as i found it working with Trusted Connections. I can not manage to build function to call stored proc using this driver.
I have working SELECT statements e.g.

```
GetUserGuid: function(dbName, userName){
    var sql = require("msnodesqlv8");

    var connectionString = "server=.;Database=" + dbName + ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}";
    var query = "SELECT uGUID FROM Users WHERE Name = '" + userName + "'";

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sql.query(connectionString, query, (err, rows) => {
            resolve(rows[0].uGUID);
        });
    })
}
```

As i did not get working correctly stored procedures calls i build function for sp following working function for SELECT statement.

```
CreateUser: function(dbName, userName){
    var sql = require("msnodesqlv8");

        var connectionString = "server=.;Database="+ dbName + ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}";
        var guid = uuidv4();
        var query = "exec dbo.CreateUser @userId='" + guid + "', @sDescription='" + userName + "'";

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            sql.query(connectionString, query, (err, rows) => {
                resolve('user created');
            });
        })
}
```

However it does not work as well.

Have you any tips Fellows?

Answer (score 1):

So, solution was problematic as i did not expect that it will be so obvious.

Example given on msnodesqlv8 package page actually works ;)

Parameters should be passed to procedure in array without any casting to expected types.

Below correct implementation for my case.

```
CreateUser: function(userName){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sql.open(settings.ConnectionString, function (err, conn) {
            //console.log(conn);
            var pm = conn.procedureMgr();
            var guid = uuidv4();
            pm.callproc('dbo.CreateUser', [guid, userName], function(err, results, output) {
                if(err != null){
                    reject('user create - failed');
                }
                else{
                     resolve('user create - succeded'); 
                }               
            });
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Miraculously, calling a stored procedure that contains a PRINT statement fails to ever finish.

So do not have any of those!